# How to create a Union type in F# that is a value type?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, f#, discriminated-union

Normal F# Discriminated Unions are reference types. How can I create a *simple* (non-recursive and with only value-type fields) union type in F# that is a value type?

Based on some internet searching my current (non-working) attempt looks as follows:

```
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type Float =
    [<DefaultValue>] [<FieldOffset 0>] val mutable Val1 : float
    [<DefaultValue>] [<FieldOffset 0>] val mutable Int1 : int
    new (a:float) = {Val1 = a}
```

[The following blog post appears to show what is possible via C#](http://jasonbock.net/Article/UnionsInDotNet)

I'm aware that the above is NOT idiomatic use of F# but I am trying to optimize the performance of a portion of my application and profiling has clearly shown that the cost of heap allocations (JIT_new) is what is causing my performance bottleneck... A simple union type is the perfect data structure for my needs, just not a heap allocated one.

Comment: Why? Are you trying to create something like a C union - F# unions are very different.  The C# trickery probably better maps to a struct.

Comment: @JohnPalmer elaborated on the **why** above. I could use an F# Struct with two fields where I will only be using one of the fields at any one time but am trying to evaluate an alternative solution.

Comment: You can [define structures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233233.aspx) in F# as well.

Comment: @GeirGrusom thanks, I know. The union type above is more compact from a memory point of view AND perhaps will obviate a lot of code that involves setting values that aren't semantically important (depending on the scenario)

Comment: You cannot (as far as I know) mix between a C union and a F# discriminated union. They're not the same thing.

You can however make your type into a structure which will turn it into a C union. This removes the GC allocation, but I don't think you can match on type any more unless you box it, at which point you're back to a GC allocation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, I would probably not do this, unless I had *very* good reasons. In most cases, the difference between structs and reference types is not really that big - in my experience, it only matters when you have a very large array of them (then structs let you allocate one big memory chunk).

That said, it looks like F# does not like the constructor code in your example. I'm really not sure why (it seems to be doing some check that does not quite work for overlapping structs), but the following does the trick:

```
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type MyStruct =
    [<DefaultValue; FieldOffset 0>] 
    val mutable Val1 : float
    [<DefaultValue; FieldOffset 0>] 
    val mutable Int1 : int
    static member Int(a:int) = MyStruct(Int1=a)
    static member Float(f:float) = MyStruct(Val1=f)
```

If I actually wanted to use this, I would add another field `Tag` containing `1` or `0` depending on which case your struct represents. Then you could pattern match on it using an active pattern and get some of the safety of discriminated unions back:

```
let (|Float|Int|) (s:MyStruct) = 
  if s.Tag = 0 then Float(s.Val1) else Int(s.Int1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not keen to do this (due to it not being idiomatic) but I have profiled (a lot) and it is pretty definitive that the heap allocation cost (showing up as a `JIT_new` call) of many small objects is a performance bottleneck and I need performance. Is their anything else I should be aware of in terms of when this might not work (due to it being a low level hack of sorts)? In other words, what are the geniune drawbacks to the above otherwise quite useful little data structure?

Comment: I think that (aside from a lack of safety), there should not be many drawbacks. It would be kind of nice optimization that the F# compiler could do for DUs containing just value types... If you're storing `int` and `float` there, is also no big copying cost (which might be the case for larger structs).

Comment: I think the active pattern might allocate one instance (when returning) and so it might not be that usable in places where you care about allocation.

Comment: But it's an instance of a value type so it shouldn't affect performance that much (or is this something `active pattern` specific)? Either way, getting the following error trying to compile the active pattern (using slightly different code): `This expression was expected to have type Choice<'a,'b> but here has type MyStruct`. I have stored Tag in the first mutable field.

Comment: Oh! I get it. The active pattern is **NOT** creating another instance of `MyStruct`, it is creating a `choice` DU (hence the heap allocation)...hmm...

Answer (score 0):

Struct unions are now supported by F#, see [F# RFC FS-1014](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.1/FS-1014-struct-discriminated-unions.md) for details. In short:

> ```
> // Single case:
>
> [<Struct>]
> type UnionExample = U of int * int * bool
>
> // Multi-case:
>
> [<Struct>]
> type Shape =
>    | Circle of radius: double
>    | Square of side: int
> ```
>
> Key differences in struct records:
>
> - You cannot have cyclic references to the same type being defined. ex: type T = U of T
> - You also cannot call the default ctor, like you could with normal F# structs.
> - For multi-case struct unions, each case must have a unique name.