# Does F# have address-of & and pointer dereference * functions?

Tags: pointers, f#, inline, unsafe, byref

In C#, I write

```
unsafe void Main() {
  float f = 3.14f;
  int i = *(int*)&f;
}
```

Is it possible to translate this code to F#?

My understanding is that a pointer is represented by the `nativeptr<'a>` type, but I for the life of me I cannot find an equivalent of the address reference `&` and pointer dereference `*` operators. I *suspect* `NativePtr.get` may be the latter, but [its implementation](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/a0fe905f093488c0dc4f6462b217b22589610054/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/nativeptr.fs#L35) escapes me, as I do not understand IL well enough.

I know about `BitConverter` and `Marshal`, but am looking for a way to implement bit mangling without copying memory.

Comment: @GuyCoder: I want to look at the *bits* of an existing float as if it was an int.

Comment: What is the purpose of this?  It is almost certainly a bad idea to write this sort of code.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: It is totally irrelevant to the question, but the intention is hashing.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Could you pretty please refrain from personal attacks on my intentions, especially without knowing them up front?

Comment: For nativeptr ops see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340434.aspx

Comment: I am not attacking I am agreeing. I did a prototype of a disassembler in F# so this is familiar. I remember having a similar problem, but I think I finally had to go with marshalling to get past the type checking.

Comment: @JohmPalmer: Thanks, and this is exactly the class that I am referencing in my own question. So is `NativePtr.get` the right substitution for C# `*` when `'T` is a primitive value type? I do not really have an idea what `ldobj` is.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Sorry, I must have misread you then, no offence taken Yes, sounds weird, but I need to bit-hash some internal collections. in `Bitconverter` there is `DoubleToInt64Bits` (which I do not need) but no `SingleToInt32Bits` (which I need, and which is no more than [`*((int*)&value`](https://github.com/mgravell/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/BitConverter.cs#L471). It would be even sillier to may taste to create a separate C# library just of this single function!

Comment: I don't know what `ldobj` does either.  You can always test this with integers / bytes / something easy or even write a comparison program to compare with C.  Having said that, `get` is pretty designed to pretend that the ptr points to an array.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: Yes, indeed I could test it, but at this moment I have not found  candidate for the other operation, the `&`. Without it, I can only shoot random addresses with `NativePtr.get`  :)

Comment: @GuyCoder: Interesting approach, thanks. That would practically solve *my original problem* (I think the JIT compiler even optimize out extra value copy on the stack in constructing this object, so there will unlikely be even a single cycle performance hit), but the question about F#'s equivalents of `&` and `*` still a different one. So no, not a duplicate.

Comment: Of interest: [How to create a Union type in F# that is a value type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405194/how-to-create-a-union-type-in-f-that-is-a-value-type)

Comment: .NET has official API for that now https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `NativePtr.get` and `set` functions read and write at an offset. If you need to read byte by byte, then use that. If you need to read at offset zero, you can use `read` and `write` instead, they will be slightly more performant.

The operator for taking "raw" address (as opposed to a `byref<_>` reference) is called `&&` ([see definition](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/a0fe905f093488c0dc4f6462b217b22589610054/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L684)).

But there is some more trickery involved, such as: you need to mark the variable `mutable` before you can take its address, you can't just store a `nativeptr<_>` value, you need to convert it to `nativeint`, plus the `nativeptr<_>` values are strongly typed, so you need to convert between them via `nativeint`, etc.

The following snippet will do the equivalent of your C# code (step by step and with full type annotations for increased clarity):

```
open FSharp.NativeInterop

let Main() =
  let mutable x: float = 3.1415
  let floatPtr: nativeint = NativePtr.toNativeInt<float> &&x
  let intPtr: nativeptr<int> = floatPtr |> NativePtr.ofNativeInt<int>
  let asInt: int = NativeInterop.NativePtr.read intPtr
  asInt
```

Or a more compact version:

```
open FSharp.NativeInterop

let Main() =
  let mutable x = 3.1415
  &&x |> NativePtr.toNativeInt |> NativePtr.ofNativeInt |> NativePtr.read<int>
```

Or package it for reuse:

```
// val inline readAs : x:'a -> 'b when 'a : unmanaged and 'b : unmanaged
let inline readAs (x: 'a) : 'b =
  let mutable x' = x
  &&x' |> NativePtr.toNativeInt |> NativePtr.ofNativeInt |> NativePtr.read<'b>

let Main() =
  let i = readAs 3.1415 : int
  ()
```

Having said all the above, I completely agree with John Palmer and GuyCoder: **please don't do this** if at all possible. This looks like exactly the kind of premature optimization that Dr. Knuth warned us about.

Comment: I agree that one should not do this if they don't know what they are doing. However, there are very good reasons to do it if you know what you are doing and need it. If you do need pointers then look at [SafeHandles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.110).aspx). If you need to do lots of low level manipulation the look at the [System.Runtime.InteropServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: This is it, thank you! Very ugly but does the trick. As for why I need that, I am copying my comment from above: “[...]I need to bit-hash some internal collections. In `BitConverter` there is `DoubleToInt64Bits` (which I do not need) but no `SingleToInt32Bits` (which I need, and which is no more than `*((int*)&value`. It would be even sillier to may taste to create a separate C# library just of this single function!” Indeed, I love things functional and pure, but sometimes those dirty bits still intrude.

Comment: Oh by the way, is the use of `inline` really warranted here, and why? There are no "caret" static types in the declaration (`^T` as opposed to `'T`). Am I missing another use case for the `inline` keyword?

Comment: No, `inline` is not strictly speaking necessary. However, if you're after performance, extra function call is a big deal. I have erroneously assumed you were after performance, because you were asking for pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Note that C#'s `float` is called `float32` in F#.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, thank you. I actually am, and this is perhaps another user case. Thanks!

Comment: Can you pls explain me what is x' and 'x I'm new to F#.

Comment: @HassanAYousef `x'` is just an identifier. Tick (aka "prime") can be part of identifiers in F#, just like numbers and underscore. `'x` is a generic type parameter.